# JQuery - How to toggle expanding/shrinking width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have so far a click function that expands the width but not sure how to toggle shrink it back to it's original width. Upon shrink, .button should read "Show details" again.

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/fpw9apmc/

```
$('.button').click(function() {
        $(".button").text("Hide Details");
        $(".expand").animate({
        width: "60%"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear'
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the edited code for your problem and [Working Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/o18tajar/) -

```
$('.button').click(function() {
            var btnText =  $(this).text();
            if(btnText === "Hide Details"){
            $(this).text("Show Details");
            $(".expand").animate({
            width: 0
            }, {
                duration: 200,
                specialEasing: {
                    width: 'linear'
                }
            });
            }else{
                $(this).text("Hide Details");
            $(".expand").animate({
            width: "60%"
            }, {
                duration: 200,
                specialEasing: {
                    width: 'linear'
                }
            });
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below script will help you.

```
var clicked = false;
var previoswidth = 0;
$('.button').click(function () {
    $(".button").text("Hide Details");
    clicked = !clicked;
    if (clicked) {
        previoswidth = $(".expand").width();
        $(".expand").animate({
            width: "60%"
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear'
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $(".expand").animate({
            width: previoswidth
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**FIDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fpw9apmc/2/)

Apply toggle functions separately to both text and width. That should do the trick

```
var width = $(".expand").width();
$('.button').click(function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, text) {
    return text === "Show Details" ? "Hide Details" : "Show Details";
  })
  var toggleWidth = $(".expand").width() == 0 ? "60%" : "0";
  $(".expand").animate({
    width: toggleWidth
  }, {
    duration: 200,
    specialEasing: {
      width: 'linear'
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a with CSS transitions, and toggling a class using jQuery.

Updated your fiddle with this: https://jsfiddle.net/oykwmj9c/2/

jQuery:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    if ($(".button").text() == "Show Details") {
    $(".button").text("Hide Details");
  } else {
    $(".button").text("Show Details");
  }  
  $(".expand").toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

CSS:

```
.expand {
  background-color: red;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.expanded {
  width: 60%
}

.button {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="expand">
  <a class="button" href="#">Show Details</a>
</div>
```